# Show a toast message after each five seconds in Background Service in Xamarin.android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I have implemented a background service. When I boot my device, the background service is started and toast message is displayed. I want a toast message to appear each 5 seconds while the service in running. The following code does not seem to be doing the job:

```
[Service]
    public class BroadcastService : Service
    {
        IBinder mBinder;

        [return: GeneratedEnum]
        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {

            Toast.MakeText(this, "BroadcastService Started...", ToastLength.Long).Show();

            DoWork();

            base.OnStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;


        }

public void DoWork()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, "BroadcastService is running at each 5 seconds...", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

Can somebody please advise what is wrong above and help to achieve this in Xamarin.android ?

Answer (score 0):

> I want a toast message to appear each 5 seconds while the service in running. The following code does not seem to be doing the job

Once `OnStartCommand` finish executing, `DoWork` won't execute any more.

According to your requirement, you need to use [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) together with [JobInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.html) to create a periodic task. For how to use JobScheduler, You can refer to the [official demo of JobScheduler](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/android5.0/JobScheduler/)